# Want to remove appended div

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a Telerik ListView and I bind it from the server side. The html for this is given below,

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
<div id="divOuterListView2" class="wrap-list">
                            <telerik:RadListView ID="RadListView2" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="DataItemHolder">
                                <LayoutTemplate>
                                    <asp:Panel ID="DataItemHolder" runat="server">
                                    </asp:Panel>
                                </LayoutTemplate>
                                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                    <div class="notif no-data">
                                        <h1>
                                            Sorry !</h2>
                                            <h2>
                                        No Data found.</h3>
                                    </div>
                                </EmptyDataTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <div class="data-item">

                                        <div class="content">
                                            <p id="p_Name" class="rs">
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblName" Width="100%" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>' />
                                            </p>
                                            <p id="p_Description" class="rs coupon-desc">
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblDescription" Width="100%" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Description") %>' />
                                            </p>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </telerik:RadListView>
                        </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

Initially 10 records are displayed in the ListView. When the user scrolls down and reaches the bottom then 10 more records are appended below the ListView by Jquery,

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        var pageIndex = 1;
        var pageCount;
        var canRun = true;

        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if (canRun == true) {
                if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > ($('.mod-footer').position().top + 30)) {
                    canRun = false;
                    sendData();
                }
            }
        });

        function sendData() {
            pageIndex++;
            if (pageIndex == 2 || pageIndex <= pageCount) {
                $("#loader").show();
                $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Records.aspx/GetRecord",
                    data: '{pageIndex: ' + pageIndex + '}',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: "true",
                    cache: "false",
                    success: OnSuccess,
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert("Failure: " + response.d);
                        $("#loader").hide();
                        canRun = true;
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert("Error: " + response.d);
                        $("#loader").hide();
                        canRun = true;
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        function OnSuccess(response) {
            var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
            var xml = $(xmlDoc);
            pageCount = parseInt(xml.find("PageCount").eq(0).find("PageCount").text());
            var deals = xml.find("Deals");

            deals.each(function () {
                var deal = $(this);
                var dataDiv = $("#divOuterListView2 div").eq(0).clone(true);

                $("#p_Name", dataDiv).html(deal.find("Name").text());
                $("#p_Description", dataDiv).html(deal.find("Description").text());
            });
            $("#loader").hide();
            canRun = true;
        }
    });
```

Now I have a DropDownList for Regions. On SelectedIndexChange of DropDownList I reload the data according to Region asynchronously.

Now the data in the ListView is changed and updated successfully but the appended data by Jquery is still there. I want to remove that data on Asynchronous post back.

On start of Ajax Request I call a Javascript function,

```
function RequestStart(sender, args) {
    $("#divOuterListView2 div").remove();
}
```

Now first time the DropDownList index is changed then the empty page is displayed and no data is showed. but the second time DropDownList is changed then the data is loaded just fine. What I am missing here? Kindly guide me?

Comment: If this is the same question as your previous one, you should edit that question to make it more clear, instead of posting a new duplicate.

Comment: Well I guess there is no solution for this issue.